# TailwindCSS throws error for dark mode classes

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm working for the first time on a tailwind css project and it throws me this error that i can't wrap my head around, i'm working with React :

`` Syntax error: The `dark:bg-gray-800` class does not exist. If `dark:bg-gray-800` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive. (8:5) ``

**index.css :**

```
@import-normalize;
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;


@layer components {
  .sidebar-icon {
    @apply relative flex items-center justify-center 
    h-12 w-12 mt-2 mb-2 mx-auto  
    bg-gray-400 hover:bg-green-600 dark:bg-gray-800 
    text-green-500 hover:text-white
    hover:rounded-xl rounded-3xl
    transition-all duration-300 ease-linear
    cursor-pointer shadow-lg ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this case, simply remove your layer.

Once you've called the dark mode into your `tailwind.config.js`, for example like this:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [],
  darkMode: 'class',
}
```

You don't need to redefine the layer component in your CSS file. See this [link](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3942) for more information about the problem

In brief, you just need to define your CSS like:

`index.css`:

```
.sidebar-icon {
@apply relative flex items-center justify-center 
   h-12 w-12 mt-2 mb-2 mx-auto  
   bg-gray-400 hover:bg-green-600 dark:bg-gray-800 
   text-green-500 hover:text-white
   hover:rounded-xl rounded-3xl
   transition-all duration-300 ease-linear
   cursor-pointer shadow-lg ;
}
```

I'm using packages version:

```
"tailwindcss": "2.2.9"
"webpack": "5.52.0"
```

Comment: @Lux Logica, I just made a mistake in the name of the file, but the config for darkmode is in tailwind.config.js, the syntax of the config confirmed this... :)

Answer (score 1):

The error warning you've posted relates to the use of a `dark:`-prefixed class - a class that is applied only in "Dark Mode". Note, that the current stable version of TailwindCSS - v2.2.15 atm - ships with "Dark Mode" classes **disabled** by default. You must explicitly enable it in your *tailwind.config.js* file, as [explained in their docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode).

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same error.

border-gray-50, but I have written it as border-grey-50, and found the same error.

Check words spellings something wrong can present same error too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).